# Present UIViewController from frame

Tags: ios, uianimation

I am showing image slider as in this order.

UIViewController > UITableview > UITableviewCell > UICollectionview > UICollectionViewCell > UIImage

User can slide UICollectionview and view images.Problem is that I need to do animation. When user tap on my UICollectionviewCell, it should animate from that cell and show full screen as in this library.

https://github.com/suzuki-0000/SKPhotoBrowser

Problem is that I need to use MWPhotoBrowser and I can't present like that.

I am thinking to use hero animation library as well.

https://github.com/lkzhao/Hero

But my view hierachy and their example is different. How shall I do?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use custom transition

**Reference:**

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CustomizingtheTransitionAnimations.html

**Code Work**

**On image selection**

add in `VC_A`

```
var selectedImage: UIImageView?
 let transition = PopAnimator()

  override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

        coordinator.animate(
          alongsideTransition: {context in
            self.bgImage.alpha = (size.width>size.height) ? 0.25 : 0.55
            self.positionListItems()
          },
          completion: nil
        )
      }
//position all images inside the list
  func positionListItems() {
    let listHeight = listView.frame.height
    let itemHeight: CGFloat = listHeight * 1.33
    let aspectRatio = UIScreen.main.bounds.height / UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let itemWidth: CGFloat = itemHeight / aspectRatio

    let horizontalPadding: CGFloat = 10.0

    for i in herbs.indices {
      let imageView = listView.viewWithTag(i) as! UIImageView
      imageView.frame = CGRect(
        x: CGFloat(i) * itemWidth + CGFloat(i+1) * horizontalPadding, y: 0.0,
        width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
    }

    listView.contentSize = CGSize(
      width: CGFloat(herbs.count) * (itemWidth + horizontalPadding) + horizontalPadding,
      height:  0)
  }

// On image selection
VC_B.transitioningDelegate = self
    present(VC_B, animated: true, completion: nil)



   // add extension
extension VC_A: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

  func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    transition.originFrame = selectedImage!.superview!.convert(selectedImage!.frame, to: nil)

    transition.presenting = true
    selectedImage!.isHidden = true

    return transition
  }

  func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    transition.presenting = false
    return transition
  }
}
```

and animation class

```
class PopAnimator: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

  let duration = 1.0
  var presenting = true
  var originFrame = CGRect.zero

  var dismissCompletion: (()->Void)?

  func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
    return duration
  }

  func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    let containerView = transitionContext.containerView

    let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to)!

    let herbView = presenting ? toView : transitionContext.view(forKey: .from)!

    let initialFrame = presenting ? originFrame : herbView.frame
    let finalFrame = presenting ? herbView.frame : originFrame

    let xScaleFactor = presenting ?

      initialFrame.width / finalFrame.width :
      finalFrame.width / initialFrame.width

    let yScaleFactor = presenting ?

      initialFrame.height / finalFrame.height :
      finalFrame.height / initialFrame.height

    let scaleTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: xScaleFactor, y: yScaleFactor)

    if presenting {
      herbView.transform = scaleTransform
      herbView.center = CGPoint(
        x: initialFrame.midX,
        y: initialFrame.midY)
      herbView.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    containerView.addSubview(toView)
    containerView.bringSubview(toFront: herbView)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay:0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.4,
      initialSpringVelocity: 0.0,
      animations: {
        herbView.transform = self.presenting ?
          CGAffineTransform.identity : scaleTransform
        herbView.center = CGPoint(x: finalFrame.midX,
                                  y: finalFrame.midY)
      },
      completion:{_ in
        if !self.presenting {
          self.dismissCompletion?()
        }
        transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
      }
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I try to read and I am not sure how to modify into my view hierarchy. 

If possible, could you please kindly advice in my demo? I have created small project for that. It need to use MWPhotoBrowser so that it can support video.
https://github.com/khantthulinn/photo_tap